# Ubuntu stuck on boot after "Started Disk Manager"

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia

I think this has something to do with the Nvidia driver update that I just did last night (nvidia-driver-515).
I've tried:

- installing the old version of the drivers and even the version before that (which I know worked).
- cleaned up my home directory to make sure there's enough space to boot.
- searched for errors with journalctl (very few errors, but one of them complained about grub and another few complained about Nvidia)
- completely purged all Nvidia packages and reinstalled the latest ones
- rebuilt my grub configuration
- added a blacklist for nouveau again

It doesn't seem to be an issue with nouveau (although it *is* starting despite being blacklisted), and I'm only getting a few warnings that I normally get other than that. I attached a list of updates that occurred the night before this happened. I am able to drop into a terminal after booting, which leads me to believe that it's an issue with plasma starting up (probably caused by graphic driver updates). Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do?

Updates: (sorry for weird formatting, ocr from a pic of my screen)

```
Start-Date: 2022-08-04 00:51:33
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: [$USER] (1000)
Upgrade:
gir1.2-gst-plugins -base-1.0:amd64 (1. 16.2-4ubuntuo. 1, 1.16.3-Oubuntu1)
gir1.2-gstreamer -1.0:amd64 (1.16.2-2, 1.16.3-Qubuntul)
gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64 (1. 16.2-4ubuntu0. 1, 1.16.3-0ubuntul)
gstreamer 1.0-g1:amd64 (1.16.2-4ubuntuo .1, 1.16.3-0ubuntu1)
gstreamer1.0-plug ins-base-apps:amd64 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0. 1, 1.16.3-Oubuntu1)
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 (1. 16.2-4ubuntuo. 1, 1. 16.3-0ubuntu1)
gstreamer1.0-plug ins-base: 1386 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0. 1, 1. 16.3-0ubuntul)
gstreamer1.0-plug ins-good: amd64 (1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1, 1.16.3-Qubuntu1)
gstreamer1.0-plug ins -good: 1386 (1. 16.2-1ubuntu2. 1, 1. 16.3-0ubuntu1)
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 (1.16.2-1ubuntu2. 1, 1.16.3-Oubuntul)
gstreamer1.0-tools:amd64 (1. 16.2-2, 1.16.3-Oubuntu1)
gstreamer 1.0-x: amd64 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0. 1, 1.16.3-0ubuntu1)
gstreamer 1.0-x: 1386 (1. 16.2-4ubuntu0. 1, 1.16.3-Oubuntu1)
1ibgstreamer-g11.0-0:amd64 (1.16.2-4ubuntuo.1, 1.16.3-Oubuntu1)
1ibgstreamer-plug ins-base1.0-0:amd64 (1. 16.2-4ubuntu0. 1, 1.16.3-0ubuntu1)
1ibgstreamer-plug ins-base1.0-0: 1386 (1. 16.2-4ubuntuo. 1, 1. 16. 3-Oubuntu1)
libgstreamer-plug ins-base1.0-dev:amd64 (1. 16.2-4ubuntu2.1, 1. 16.3-0ubuntu1)
libgstreamer-plug ins-good1. 0-0: amd64 (1. 16.2-1ubuntu2. 1, 1.16.3-0ubuntu1)
libgstreamer-plug ins -good1.0-0: 1386 (1.16.2-1ubuntu2. 1, 1.16.3-0ubuntu1)
libgstreamer 1.0-0:amd64 (1. 16.2-2, 1.16.3-0ubuntu1)
1ibgstreamer 1 0-0: 1386 (1. 16.2-2, 1.16.3-0ubuntu1)
libgstreamer 1.0-dev:amd64 (1. 16.2-2, 1. 16.3-Oubuntu1)
libnetplano :amd64 (0. 109-0ubuntu2^20 .04.1, 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2)
libnv idia-cfg1-510:amd64 (510. 73.05-Oubuntu0.20 .04. 1, 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.20.04. 1)
libnvidia-common-510: amd64 (510. 73. 05-Oubuntuo.20.04.1, 510.85.02-Oubuntu0.20.04.1)
libnvidia-compute-510:amd64 (510. 73. 05-Oubuntuo . 20.04. 1, 510.85.02-oubuntu0.20.04. 1)
libnv idia-compute-510: 1386 (510. 73. 05-Oubuntu0.20 .04.1, 510.85.02-0ubuntuo.20.04. 1)
libnv idia-decode-510:amd64 (510. 73. 05-oubuntuo .20 . 04. 1, 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
1 ibnv idia-decode-510: 1386 (510. 73. 05-Oubuntuo.20 .04.1, 510.85.02-oubuntu0.20.04.1)
libnv idia-encode-510:amd64 (510. 73.05-Oubuntu0 .20 . 04.1, 510.85.02-Oubuntu0.20.04. 1)
1 ibnv idia-encode-510: 1386 (510. 73.05-0ubuntuo . 20.04. 1, 510.85.02-Oubuntuo.20.04.1)
libnvidia-extra-510: amd64 (510. 73. 05-Oubuntu0.20 .04.1, 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.20 .04.1)
1 ibnv idia-fbc1-510:amd64 (510. 73. 05-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.20 .04.1)
libnv idia-fbc1-510: 1386 (510. 73. 05-Oubuntu0.20 .04. 1, 510.85.02-Oubuntu.20.04.1)
1ibnvidia-g1-510: amd64 (510. 73. 05-Oubuntu0 . 20.04. 1, 510.65.02-Oubuntuo.20.04.1)
libnvidia-g1-510: 1386 (510. 73.05-Oubuntuo.20.04.1, 510.85.02-Oubuntu0.20.04.1)
linux-firmwuare:amd64 (1.187.32, 1.187.33)
netplan. io:amd64 (0.104-Oubuntu2^"20.04. 1, 0.104-Oubuntu2""20.04.2)
nv idia-compute -ut 1 1s-510: amd64 (510. 73.05-Oubuntu0.20 .04. 1, 510. 85. 02-oubuntu0. 20.04. 1)
nvidia-dkms-510: amd64 (510. 73. 05-0ubuntuo . 20.04. 1, 510. 85.02-0ubuntu0.20 .04.1)
nvidla-driver-510:amd64 (510. 73.05-0ubuntu0. 20.09. 1, 510.85.02-Oubuntuo.20.04. 1)
nv idia-kernel-common-510: amd64 (510. 73. 05-Oubuntu0.20 .04.1, 510.85.02-0ubuntuo,20.04. 1)
nv idia-kernel-source-510: amd64 (510. 73. 05-0ubuntu0. 20. 04. 1, 510.85.02-Oubuntu0.20.04.1)
nvidia-ut ils-510:amd64 (510.73.05-Oubuntuo.20 .04. 1, 510.85.02-Oubuntuo.20.04.1)
xserver-xorg-v ideo-nv idia-510: amd64 (510. 73. 05-oubuntu0. 20.04. 1, 510.85.02-Oubuntu0. 20.04.1),

End-Date: 2022-08-04 00:55:37
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `sudo apt purge *nvidia* && sudo apt install *nvidia-*-515*` plus a reboot didn't do anything, but this worked:

- `sudo apt purge *nvidia*`
- reboot
- use the now working GUI to add the nvidia drivers through the 'additional drivers' tab of the software and updates application.
- reboot
  Seems to be fine now